# Pattern matching and infinite streams

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation

So, I'm working to teach myself Scala, and one of the things I've been playing with is the `Stream` class. I tried to use a naïve translation of the [classic Haskell version of Dijkstra's solution](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/blog/posts/Hamming/) to the Hamming number problem:

```
object LazyHammingBad {
  private def merge(a: Stream[BigInt], b: Stream[BigInt]): Stream[BigInt] =
    (a, b) match {
      case (x #:: xs, y #:: ys) =>
        if (x < y) x #:: merge(xs, b)
        else if (y < x) y #:: merge(a, ys)
        else x #:: merge(xs, ys)
    }

  val numbers: Stream[BigInt] =
    1 #:: merge(numbers map { _ * 2 },
      merge(numbers map { _ * 3 }, numbers map { _ * 5 }))
}
```

Taking this for a spin in the interpreter led quickly to disappointment:

```
scala> LazyHammingBad.numbers.take(10).toList
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I decided to look to see if other people had solved the problem in Scala using the Haskell approach, and adapted [this solution](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#Scala) from Rosetta Code:

```
object LazyHammingGood {
  private def merge(a: Stream[BigInt], b: Stream[BigInt]): Stream[BigInt] =
    if (a.head < b.head) a.head #:: merge(a.tail, b)
    else if (b.head < a.head) b.head #:: merge(a, b.tail)
    else a.head #:: merge(a.tail, b.tail)

  val numbers: Stream[BigInt] = 
    1 #:: merge(numbers map {_ * 2}, 
            merge(numbers map {_ * 3}, numbers map {_ * 5}))
}
```

This one worked nicely, but I still wonder how I went wrong in `LazyHammingBad`. Does using  `#::` to destructure `x #:: xs` force the evaluation of `xs` for some reason? Is there any way to use pattern matching safely with infinite streams, or do you just have to use `head` and `tail` if you don't want things to blow up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`a match {case x#::xs =>...` is about the same as `val (x, xs) = (a.head, a.tail)`. So the difference between the bad version and the good one, is that in that in the bad version, you're calling `a.tail` and `b.tail` right at the start, instead of just use them to build the tail of the resulting stream. Furthermore when you use them at the right of `#::` (not pattern matching, but building the result, as in `#:: merge(a.b.tail)` you are not actually calling merge, that will be done only later, when accessing the tail of the returned Stream. So in the good version, a call to merge does not call `tail` at all. In the bad version, it calls it right at start.

Now if you consider numbers, or even a simplified version, say `1 #:: merge(numbers, anotherStream)`, when you call you call `tail` on that (as `take(10)` will), `merge` has to be evaluated. You call `tail` on `numbers`, which call `merge` with `numbers` as parameters, which calls `tails` on `numbers`, which calls `merge`, which calls `tail`...

By contrast, in super lazy Haskell, when you pattern match, it does barely any work.  When you do `case l of x:xs`, it will evaluate `l` just enough to know whether it is an empty list or a cons. 
If it is indeed a cons, `x` and `xs` will be available as two thunks, functions that will eventually give access, later, to content. The closest equivalent in Scala would be to just test `empty`.

Note also that in Scala Stream, while the `tail` is lazy, the `head` is not. When you have a (non empty) Stream, the head has to be known. Which means that when you get the tail of the stream, itself a stream, its head, that is the second element of the original stream, has to be computed. This is sometimes problematic, but in your example, you fail before even getting there.

Comment: I am using `lazy val solution: List[Move] = pathsToGoal match {
    case (_, moveHistory) #:: _ => moveHistory.reverse
    case _ => List.empty[Move]
  }` and this does not evaluates tail. Is it because I am using _ ? Here in this case pathsToGoal is an infinite Stream

Answer (score 6):

Note that you can do what you want by defining a better pattern matcher for `Stream`:

Here's a bit I just pulled together in a [Scala Worksheet](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started):

```
object HammingTest {
  // A convenience object for stream pattern matching
  object #:: {
    class TailWrapper[+A](s: Stream[A]) {
      def unwrap = s.tail
    }
    object TailWrapper {
      implicit def unwrap[A](wrapped: TailWrapper[A]) = wrapped.unwrap
    }
    def unapply[A](s: Stream[A]): Option[(A, TailWrapper[A])] = {
      if (s.isEmpty) None
      else {
        Some(s.head, new TailWrapper(s))
      }
    }
  }

  def merge(a: Stream[BigInt], b: Stream[BigInt]): Stream[BigInt] =
    (a, b) match {
      case (x #:: xs, y #:: ys) =>
        if (x < y) x #:: merge(xs, b)
        else if (y < x) y #:: merge(a, ys)
        else x #:: merge(xs, ys)
    }                                             //> merge: (a: Stream[BigInt], b: Stream[BigInt])Stream[BigInt]

  lazy val numbers: Stream[BigInt] =
    1 #:: merge(numbers map { _ * 2 }, merge(numbers map { _ * 3 }, numbers map { _ * 5 }))
                                                  //> numbers  : Stream[BigInt] = <lazy>
  numbers.take(10).toList                         //> res0: List[BigInt] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12)
}
```

Now you just need to make sure that Scala finds your `object #::` instead of the one in `Stream.class` whenever it's doing pattern matching. To facilitate that, it might be best to use a different name like `#>:` or `##::` and then just remember to always use that name when pattern matching.

If you ever need to match the empty stream, use `case Stream.Empty`. Using `case Stream()` will attempt to evaluate your entire stream there in the pattern match, which will lead to sadness.