# Implementing Stream.toList

Tags: scala

Here's my attempt at [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/)'s exercise to write `toList` for the `Stream` class.

```
def toList[A](stream: Stream[A]): List[A] = {
    def go(s: Stream[A], acc: List[A]): List[A] = s match {
        case x #:: xs => go(xs, acc :+ x)
        case _ => acc
    }
    go(stream, Nil)
}
```

Based on reading (but not understanding all) of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7492715/409976), I was unsure if my pattern matching was correct. In particular, I was concerned that my first **case** was resulting in immediately evaluating the tail of stream.

Conceptually, I think that I need to implement `toList` where each recursion step adds the head of the stream to the list, **not** evaluating the tail for each step.

Am I correct in this understanding and the above implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs and source for `Stream` addresses this pretty well.

The source for `#::` is:

```
  object #:: {
    def unapply[A](xs: Stream[A]): Option[(A, Stream[A])] =
      if (xs.isEmpty) None
      else Some((xs.head, xs.tail))
  }
```

The relevant part of this is `Some((xs.head, xs.tail))`. The [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L1) for `tail` states that:

> Note that this method does not force evaluation of the `Stream` but
>   merely returns the lazy result.

Based on the docs `xs` does not get evaluated in the case statement `case x #:: xs`. If this case matches, then `go(xs, acc :+ x)` is called. `xs` here is essentially `s.tail` which is not evaluated as noted above.

The code in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7492715/409976) you linked to is different in that tail( a `Stream`) is used in recursive calls to `merge` and is then `unapply` is called on it destructuring it into it's head and tail. Since the `head` is a `Stream` it gets evaluated and will stack overflow on large enough inputs. @Didier Dupont states this nicely too:

> Note also that in Scala Stream, while the tail is lazy, the head is
>   not. When you have a (non empty) Stream, the head has to be known.
>   Which means that when you get the tail of the stream, itself a stream,
>   its head, that is the second element of the original stream, has to be
>   computed. This is sometimes problematic, but in your example, you fail
>   before even getting there.

The extraction of `head` and `tail` for  `xs` in your code won't have this issue unless `A` is a `Stream`. i.e. a stream of streams. The code in the other post creates this situation via the recursive call `merge`.